# Write a wrapper around SVN and Git that executes on a server

Tags: c++, git, svn

I'm looking into how to build a tool that will handle interacting with SVN or Git on a server, basically I need to manage their repositories, and be able to wrap around their functionality. And this all needs to run on a server, so I can't just run their command line interfaces.

I've been looking into SVN's source code, and into libgit2 for interacting with Git, but that seems like it'll be a lot of work and I want to make sure this hasn't already been solved somewhere.

Ideally I'd like to find a solution that is easy to develop and maintain, that allows for full interaction with SVN and Git, and can run on a high capacity server, is there a way for me to do this without rewriting a lot of base SVN and Git functionality?

Comment: "so I can't just run their command line interfaces" - why not? You can still shell out to them as long as you're careful. There's good Java libraries for both SVN and git - reimplementing everything in Java I think - if you can switch to Java.

Comment: I dunno SVN but git is pretty self-sustained. Wrapping could only hurt. Please explain why direct access is not an option to provide meaningful help.

Comment: My issue is that by spinning up a command prompt on a server we run into c10k faster. We want to maintain as many clients as possible, so we're actively trying to find a solution that avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

For Git, link to libgit2.  http://libgit2.github.com/  It has bindings for most languages that allow you to just get to work.

Unless you're doing something crazy weird, you can probably find a shrink-wrapped package that does what you want without coding.  Remember that the most perfect program is the one you didn't have to write.

Comment: Yeah, that what I've been looking into lately, good to hear I'm on the right track.

And I may be doing something crazy, but right now it's just some R&D.